# Android: How to use extend ListActivity in extend Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, listactivity

How to get the ListActivity properly into fragment? I always get an error.

I have this fragment:

```
public class Tools extends Fragment {

    public Tools(){}
    RelativeLayout view;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tools, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Tools");
        return view;
    }
}
```

and I want to use this Extend ListActivity in that fragment:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    private String URL_ITEMS = "http://192.168.1.88/asd/getFixture.php";
    private static final String TAG_FIXTURE = "fixture";
    private static final String TAG_MATCHID = "matchId";
    private static final String TAG_TEAMA = "teamA";
    private static final String TAG_TEAMB = "teamB";
    JSONArray matchFixture = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> matchFixtureList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Call Async task to get the match fixture
        new GetFixture().execute();
    }
    private class GetFixture extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
            ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
            Log.d("url: ", "> " + URL_ITEMS);
            String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_ITEMS,ServiceHandler.GET);
            // print the json response in the log
            Log.d("Get match fixture response: ", "> " + json);
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d("try", "in the try");
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    matchFixture = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FIXTURE);
                    Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
                    int len = matchFixture.length();
                    Log.d("len", "get array length");
                    for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
                        String matchId = c.getString(TAG_MATCHID);
                        Log.d("matchId", matchId);
                        String teamA = c.getString(TAG_TEAMA);
                        Log.d("teamA", teamA);
                        String teamB = c.getString(TAG_TEAMB);
                        Log.d("teamB", teamB);
                        //  hashmap for single match
                        HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_MATCHID, matchId);
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_TEAMA, teamA);
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_TEAMB, teamB);
                        matchFixtureList.add(matchFixture);
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    MainActivity.this, matchFixtureList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                    TAG_MATCHID, TAG_TEAMA,TAG_TEAMB
            }
                    , new int[] {
                    R.id.matchId,R.id.teamA,
                    R.id.teamB
            }
            );
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

This is the code by which I tried to put that ListActivity into Fragment:

```
public class terbaru extends Fragment {

    public terbaru(){}
    RelativeLayout view;
    private String URL_ITEMS = "http://192.168.1.88/asd/getFixture.php";
    private static final String TAG_FIXTURE = "fixture";
    private static final String TAG_MATCHID = "matchId";
    private static final String TAG_TEAMA = "teamA";
    private static final String TAG_TEAMB = "teamB";
    JSONArray matchFixture = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> matchFixtureList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.terbarus, container, false);
        // Call Async task to get the match fixture
        new GetFixture().execute();
    }

    private class GetFixture extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {
            ServiceHandler serviceClient = new ServiceHandler();
            Log.d("url: ", "> " + URL_ITEMS);
            String json = serviceClient.makeServiceCall(URL_ITEMS,ServiceHandler.GET);
            // print the json response in the log
            Log.d("Get match fixture response: ", "> " + json);
            if (json != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d("try", "in the try");
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    Log.d("jsonObject", "new json Object");
                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    matchFixture = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_FIXTURE);
                    Log.d("json aray", "user point array");
                    int len = matchFixture.length();
                    Log.d("len", "get array length");
                    for (int i = 0; i < matchFixture.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = matchFixture.getJSONObject(i);
                        String matchId = c.getString(TAG_MATCHID);
                        Log.d("matchId", matchId);
                        String teamA = c.getString(TAG_TEAMA);
                        Log.d("teamA", teamA);
                        String teamB = c.getString(TAG_TEAMB);
                        Log.d("teamB", teamB);
                        //  hashmap for single match
                        HashMap<String, String> matchFixture = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_MATCHID, matchId);
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_TEAMA, teamA);
                        matchFixture.put(TAG_TEAMB, teamB);
                        matchFixtureList.add(matchFixture);
                    }
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.d("catch", "in the catch");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    terbaru.this, matchFixtureList,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                    TAG_MATCHID, TAG_TEAMA,TAG_TEAMB
            }
                    , new int[] {
                    R.id.matchId,R.id.teamA,
                    R.id.teamB
            }
            );
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            return view;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not extend multiple class in java. To implement listview in Fragment you have to implement using Recyleview or listview manually or you can you extend ListFragment to implement ListActivity